# How to convert a Sequence of scala.xml.Attribute to scala.xml.MetaData?

Tags: scala, scala-xml

There's not much to add here. Of course I'm able to get it done somehow with an imperative coding style, but I'm curious how this can be solved nicely.

```
def this( arguments: Seq[(String, String)], merges: Seq[(String, String)]) = this
{
    val metadata: Seq[Attribute] = ( arguments ++ merges ).groupBy( _._1 ).map
    {
        case (key, value) => Attribute( None, key, Text( value.map( _._2 ).mkString( " " ) ), Null )
    }

    var result: MetaData = Null

    for( m <- metadata ) result = result.append( m )

    result
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
metadata.fold(Null)((soFar, attr) => soFar append attr)
```

So you can do away with intermediate variable altogether if you are so inclined.
In full:

```
def foo(arguments: Seq[(String, String)], merges: Seq[(String, String)]) =
  (arguments ++ merges).groupBy(_._1).map {
    case (key, value) => Attribute(None, key, Text(value.map(_._2).mkString(" ")), Null)
  }.fold(Null)((soFar, attr) => soFar append attr)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at fold. I've been overlooking this method so far struggling around with foldLeft and ugly type errors. `.fold( Null )( _ append _ )` is just what I need.